# Shimming in Swift

Tags: ios, macos, swift

According to Apple engineer Elizabeth Reid "shimming" is when you use conditional compilation to reuse code between iOS and OS X. For example:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
@import UIKit;
#define BaseView UIView
#else
@import AppKit;
#define BaseView NSView
#endif

@interface MyView : BaseView

@end
```

In the WWDC 2014 session [Sharing code between iOS and OS X](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/233) she also states:

> If you literally translate how you would shim with Objective-C, this
>   will not compile in Swift.
>
> There are ways to shim your code in Swift.
>
> But it gets more complicated than your basic conditional compilation
>   that we can use in Objective-C.

So, which are the ways to "shim your code" in Swift?

Comment: take a look on this: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html, especially the _conditional compilation statements_. that may be answer to your question.

Comment: @holex From the same document: "In contrast with condition compilation statements in the C preprocessor, conditional compilation statements in Swift must completely surround blocks of code that are self-contained and syntactically valid." On a re-read, I think that's what Reid might have meant by "more complicated".

Answer (score 33):

that would look like this in *Swift*:

```
#if os(iOS)
    import UIKit
    typealias BaseClass = UIView
    #else
    import AppKit
    typealias BaseClass = NSView
#endif

//

class MyClass : BaseClass {

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Neat. Didn't think of `typealias`. Can't get it working on a playground, but will try it later in a project.

Comment: I have not used the playground ever, but in a project the _Xcode6 beta2_ can already deal with it properly on my side.